# WP Ajax Form not passing $_GET

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

$_GET not passing into my ajax callback function here is my code.

$_GET not passing therefore I can't query the posts with terms on WP_Query.

I want to do is ; get $_get values from form via AJAX and Run WP_Query. I use bootstrap multiselect in form.

functions.php ;

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_filter_search', 'my_ajax_filter_search_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_filter_search', 'my_ajax_filter_search_callback');

function my_ajax_filter_search_callback() {

    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

    $tax_query = array();

    if($_GET['app_category_multi']) {
        $app_cat = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['app_category_multi'] );
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'app_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $app_cat,
            'operator' => 'AND'
        );
    }
  
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'playbook',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => $meta_query,
        'tax_query' => $tax_query
    );


    $search_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) {

        $result = array();

        while ( $search_query->have_posts() ) {
            $search_query->the_post();
            $result[] = array(
                "title" => get_the_title(),
                "permalink" => get_permalink(),
                "short_images" => get_short_images(),
                "get_tags" => get_tags_item(),
                "short_description" => get_field('short_description')

            );
        }
        wp_reset_query();

        echo json_encode($result);

    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
    wp_die();

}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You haven't shared your JS request part of the code. May be you are sending post request? Anyway, try $_REQUEST['app_category_multi'] instead of $_GET['app_category_multi'].

Answer (score 0):

Using the wordpress function `get_query_var()` you can do the following:

```
function my_ajax_filter_search_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'app_category_multi';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_ajax_filter_search_query_vars' );
```

and then in your code

```
if(get_query_var( 'app_category_multi')) {
    $app_cat = sanitize_text_field( get_query_var( 'app_category_multi') );
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'app_category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $app_cat,
        'operator' => 'AND'
    );
}
```

more information is available in the wordpress documentation - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried that but it still returns null.

Comment: Therefore, query runs without tax_query params.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is from Bootstrap Multiselect library. I added 3 hidden inputs for them. After that I updated their value with jQuery.

Input value's have been turned to array with php's explode and put in tax_query with WP_Query.

If you have this "rare" problem like this, It's not from WordPress. It's from multiselect lib.

Thanks a lot to all contributers.